# Simple newline in equation

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I'm trying to line-break in the middle of a series of defined matrices. The code looks like:

```
\begin{equation}
I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \imath \\ -\imath & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \\ 
Z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},
H = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix},
S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \imath \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
```

However the matrices appear all in one line.

Comment: Use `gather` or `align` instead of `equation`. Side note: are you sure you want to use `\imath` here? Why not just `i`?

Comment: Thanks! It seems like \begin{split} was a good fix for this. Also I used \imath because I will potentially use many different i's in my paper, so I want to stylize them so that readers can differentiate.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on Argos suggestion. In this case I'd use

```
\begin{gather*}
I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \imath \\ -\imath & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \\ 
Z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
H = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \imath \end{pmatrix}.
\end{gather*}
```

no numbering and better space

Alignment and a single number

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
I &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},  
  & % seperation
X &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, 
  &
Y &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \imath \\ -\imath & 0 \end{pmatrix}, 
 \\ 
Z &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, 
  &
H &= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, 
  &
S &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \imath \end{pmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
```

Please see the `amsmath` manual for for details

The two examples will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works too! However in this case there is absolutely no numbering which isn't ideal either. So far the {split} method works  so I think I'll use that

Comment: That is not a good idea as split can only handle one alignment row, I'll make an update

Answer (score 0):

Try using `align` from the `AMS-math` package for multi-line equations, it's a lot easier.

```
\begin{align}
I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \imath \\ -\imath & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \\ 
Z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},
H = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix},
S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \imath \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: This would be helpful, however each new-line in the align enviornment is enumerated. so each line of these matricies would be denoted (1) and (2) on the far right.

Comment: See my follow up to Argos suggestion